# how to assert ng-touched ng-pristine ng-valid class attribute in cypress?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, cypress

This is the input:

I tried this way, but it is not working

```js
it('Verify form fields',()=>{
      cy.get('.content-card>div>form>mat-form-field>div>div:nth-child(1)>.mat-form-field-infix>input')
         .should('have.length',2)
         .then(($el)=>{
               expect($el.eq(0)).to.have.class('mat-input-element ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid')

         } )
```

Please help me to assert ng-touched ng-pristine ng-valid class attribute in cypress?

Answer (score 0):

What does "is not working" mean? Read the error messages, that should give you enough pointers.

This should work just fine:

```js
cy.get('...')
  .should('have.class', 'ng-touched')
  .should('have.class', 'ng-pristine')
  .should('have.class', 'ng-valid');
```

I also think that you should find a better selector for `cy.get()` than this ".content-card>div>form>mat-form-field>div>div:nth-child(1)>.mat-form-field-infix>input", it's too long and unreadable.